# Linear span and consistency of liner system

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$, and $T=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. The augmented matrix $(u_1 u_2 u_3 |v_1 |v_2 |v_3)$ has RREF(linear system inconsistent for $v_2.$)

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & |-1 & | 0 &| 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1 &| 1&|0&|-2\\0&0&0&|0&|1&|0\end{bmatrix}

and $(v_1 v_2 v_3 | u_1 |u_2 |u_3)$ has RREF (linear system consistent for all $u_1,u_2,u_3$)

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&|-2&|-1&|-5\\0&1&0&|0&|0&|0\\0&0&1&|-1&|-1&|-3\end{bmatrix}
So $\text{span}(T)$ is not contained in $\text{span}(S)$ since $v_2$, which is in $T$ is not a linear combination of $u_1,u_2$,and $u_3$ (inconsistent linear system).

Whereas on the other hand $\text{span}(S)$ is contained in $\text{span}(T)$ since every vector in $S$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the v1,v2,v3 (consistent linear system).

My question is : can I say that $v_2$ is not in $\text{span}(S)$ but $v_1$ is in $\text{span}(S)$?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $v_1$ is in the span of the vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$ it is enough to recognize that:
$$u_1-u_2=v_1$$
Moreover $v_2$ cannot be in the span of $u_1,u_2,u_3$ as given any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have: $$au_1+bu_2+cu_3$$ has a zero third component, and thus there is no $a,b,c$ such that the third component would be -1. Thus $v_2$ is not in the span.
I hope this answers your question.